# Workaround for GNU Make 3.80 eval bug

Tags: makefile, eval, gnu-make

I'm trying to create a generic build template for my Makefiles, kind of like they discuss in the [eval documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/make/Eval-Function.html#Eval-Function).

I've run into a known bug with GNU Make 3.80.  When $(eval) evaluates a line that is over 193 characters, Make crashes with a "Virtual Memory Exhausted" error.

The code I have that causes the issue looks like this.

```
SRC_DIR = ./src/

PROG_NAME = test

define PROGRAM_template
  $(1)_SRC_DIR = $$(SRC_DIR)$(1)/
  $(1)_SRC_FILES = $$(wildcard $$($(1)_SRC_DIR)*.c)
  $(1)_OBJ_FILES = $$($(1)_SRC_FILES):.c=.o)

  $$($(1)_OBJ_FILES) : $$($(1)_SRC_FILES) # This is the problem line
endef

$(eval $(call PROGRAM_template,$(PROG_NAME)))
```

When I run this Makefile, I get

```
gmake: *** virtual memory exhausted.  Stop.
```

The expected output is that all .c files in ./src/test/ get compiled into .o files (via an implicit rule).

The problem is that $$($(1)_SRC_FILES) and $$($(1)_OBJ_FILES) are together over 193 characters long (if there are enough source files).

I have tried running the make file on a directory where there is only 2 .c files, and it works fine.  It's only when there are many .c files in the SRC directory that I get the error.

I know that GNU Make 3.81 fixes this bug.  Unfortunately I do not have the authority or ability to install the newer version on the system I'm working on.  I'm stuck with 3.80.

So, is there some workaround?  Maybe split $$($(1)_SRC_FILES) up and declare each dependency individually within the eval?

Comment: i just experienced this issue with 3.81 version too (ubuntu 10.10)

Comment: If you have a workaround for this I'm interested on how you did it.

Comment: Also, do you have the bug report or ID so that I can reference it?

Answer (score 5):

lol hacks

```
ifneq (3.81,$(shell (echo $(MAKE_VERSION); echo 3.81) | sort | head -n1))

make-3.81/make:
        wget -nc http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/make/make-3.81.tar.gz
        gzip -cd make-3.81.tar.gz | tar xvf -
        cd make-3.81 && ./configure --prefix=$$(pwd)
        $(MAKE) -C make-3.81 make

%: make-3.81/make
        make-3.81/make $@

else

# rest of your makefile

endif
```

Seriously though, there can't possibly be anything preventing you from installing 3.81, even if it is only locally.

Comment: Actually, the computer is not connected to the internet, so your hack wont work.  Further, it is against my company's policy for me to install any software on the machine.  Even locally.  I'm not saying it makes sense, I'm just saying its the rules.  I really can't just go install 3.81.

Comment: Include the new version in your source tree.

Comment: In addition to bengineerd's response ... Furthermore, this problem isn't fixed in 3.82, so that hack is absolutely useless for this problem.

Comment: @PavelShved what are you talking about? This is not an answer so much as it's a sarcastic taunt. This doesn't answer the question in any way. the OP already knows his version doesn't resolve the problem, and he has no way to upgrade, Briant Vanderberg even addressed that 3.82 still has the problem, and this answer does not answer the OP question. That means a downvote. You should check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer if you truly have no idea what constitutes a good answer or not.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps nobody needs this any more, but I guess clever use of `include` could overcome this kind of limitation.

Replace `define PROGRAM_template` with something like:

```
define PROGRAM_template
__template_arg := $(1)
include PROGRAM_template.mk
endef
```

Create `PROGRAM_template.mk` to implement the core of the template macro:

```
$(__template_arg)_SRC_DIR = $(SRC_DIR)$(__template_arg)/
$(__template_arg)_SRC_FILES = $(wildcard $($(__template_arg)_SRC_DIR)*.c)
$(__template_arg)_OBJ_FILES = $($(__template_arg)_SRC_FILES:.c=.o)

$($(__template_arg)_OBJ_FILES) : $($(__template_arg)_SRC_FILES)
__template_arg :=
```

Of course, this is a bit ugly (use of global variable to pass argument to what technically is a macro). I like the first answer better... :-)