# gnu make 3.80 source with eval bug fix

Tags: makefile

Where can I get the gnu make 3.80 with "eval" bug fix? Is there any repository for 3.80 + daily builds?  Installing latest gnu make is not an option for me.

Thanks,

Comment: The latest make is 3.82. Are you able to install 3.81? If not, why?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2428506/789750) might be helpful in the meantime.

Comment: Our legacy cross compiler uses 3.80 and I'm NOT allowed to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a simple [patch](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/download.php?file_id=120) posted in the original [bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?1517).